# RS485 registers for calculating total power consumption (kwh)

Tags: energy, rs485, modbus, power-meter

I have an energy meter (OHIO A2000) which has been now discontinued by the manufacturer. Anyway, I'm following [the manual](https://www.gossenmetrawatt.com/resources/ec/a2000/a2000-sb_modbus1_gb.pdf) for extracting energy parameters through Modbus RS485 communication. I'm getting most of the parameters accurately (i.e, A, VLL, KW, PF..) but I'm having trouble getting the total kWh value from the attached picture.
How can I get the total kWh value 819371.8 from the Modbus registers?

---

[image: A2000 display]

---

`2018-12-21 13:45:52.367 <02048>     34  32645     49   1399     41 -18381    125  15663     25 -19692     31  20483     39  19877     96  20668`

---

This is the data log from register 0800h-080fh. These are represented as EnergyMeters in the manual. These should be multiplied with 10^2 to get the actual values.(Dim.P = 2). But I'm having trouble in interpreting these values, which entry belongs to what value? Also, I don't see any entry from these values would result in the total kWh (819371.8).

Comment: That number 819371.8 seems to be labelled k     Wh, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: 2018-12-21 13:45:52.367 <02048>     34  32645     49   1399     41 -18381    125  15663     25 -19692     31  20483     39  19877     96  20668

Comment: This is the data log from register 0800h-080fh. These are represented as EnergyMeters in the manual. These should be multiplied with 10^2 to get the actual values.(Dim.P = 2). But I'm having trouble in interpreting these values, which entry belongs to what value? Also, I don't see any entry from these values would result in the total kWh (819371.8) @SolarMike

Comment: Which mode are you using? L123 ot LTHT

Comment: (125 * 2^16 + 15663) * 100 = 820766300, which is close to the value in that picture.

Comment: @SolarMike it's L123 mode.

Comment: @BeB00 oh yeah indeed it's a day old picture, so the readings might have incremented. may I know more about the formula?

Comment: In that mode, the active readings are shown as negative.

Comment: @imvinaypatil the reading itself is a 32 bit value, but the modbus is sending it as two 16 bit values, MSB first. In order to get the correct result, you left shift the first value by 16 (which is the same as multiplying by 2^16) and add it to the second value

Comment: @BeB00 How about the decimal precision? Do I need to multiply it with 100 or 0.1?

Comment: @imvinaypatil I guess 0.1 if you want kWH, and 100 if you want WH.